# Campo enum en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, enum

tengo un código donde saco varios valores y si es una cosa u otra me debe mostrar unos botones en concreto.
Este es el código

```
$sql = "SELECT d.*, f.* FROM datosPersonales d INNER JOIN foto f ON f.idFoto = d.idFoto WHERE login='$_SESSION[usuarioLogin]'";
$dato = mysqli_query($enlace, $sql); 


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dato,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 echo "<form action='fichaDatosPers.php' method='post'>";
 echo "<table class='tabla'>";
 echo "<tr><td>Nombre: " . $row['nombre'] . "&nbsp;<input type='text' name='modifNombre'>&nbsp;<input name='modif' type='submit' style='left:30%' class='botonModificar' value='Modificar'></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td>Apellidos: " . $row['apellidos'] . "&nbsp;<input type='text' name='modifApell'>&nbsp;<input name='modif2' type='submit' style='left:20.5%' class='botonModificar' value='Modificar'></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td>Email: " . $row['email'] . "&nbsp;<input type='text' name='modifEmail'>&nbsp;<input name='modif3' type='submit' style='left:7%' class='botonModificar' value='Modificar'></td></tr>";
 if($row["rol"] == "Gerente"){
  echo "<tr><td><a href='#popup'>Abrir Popup</a><td>";
  echo "<td><input type='submit' value='Eliminar cuenta' name='eliminar'></td></tr>";               
  echo "<tr><td class='foto'><img src='" . $row["foto"] .  "' width='400' heigth='600'></td></tr>";
  echo "<div id='popup' class='overlay'>
            <div id='popupBody'>
                 <h2>Título de la ventana</h2>
                 <a id='cerrar' href='#'>&times;</a>
                 <div class='popupContent'>
                      <p>Este es el contenido</p>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>";
  echo "</table>";
  echo "</form>";
 }else{
  echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' value='Eliminar cuenta' name='eliminar'></td></tr>";               
  echo "<tr><td class='foto'><img src='" . $row["foto"] .  "' width='400' heigth='600'></td></tr>";
  echo "</table>";
  echo "</form>";
 }
}
```

El campo rol es un enum que puede ser Gerente o usuario. La página no me muestra nada pero tampoco me da errores.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Haz un var_dump($row["rol"]);exit; antes del "if($row["rol"] == "Gerente")" y dinos que es lo que muestra.

Comment: No muestra nada

Comment: No te muestra nada de nada?, es decir tampoco te muestra los `echo` antes del if else?

Comment: nada de nada, ni da errores. Y es cuadno añadí el if con el enum, antes se mostraba todo bien.

Comment: A ver, si no te muestra el var_dump, eso es que la consulta o no se está haciendo bien, o la conexión de la bdd está mal, porque el campo "rol" no contiene datos.

Comment: Antes de meter el if con el enum tenia lo mismo pero sin eso y me lo mostraba todo bien. Asi que yo creo que no va a ser eso, además hice un mysqli_error() y no me dio errores.

Comment: Entonces comenta todo el codigo dentro del while y pon solo var_dump($row), así verás en cada uno de los loops qué es lo que contiene ese array, por otra parte en el if puedes forzar que $row['rol'] sea string, tal que así ` if((string) $row["rol"] == "Gerente")`

Comment: @saralópezsuárez, ¿has validado en la `DB` que en la tabla `datosPersonales` todo los registros tengan `rol` distinto de vacío? Los campos `enum` tienen un pequeño problema y es que si a la hora de agregar/actualizar un registro y no establecer correctamente este dato, puede no fallar (por una config del MySQL) y quedar vacío (dado que el valor no coincide con ninguno de los configurados).

Comment: Tienes un poco de lío en tu código, por ejemplo, abres una etiqueta `form` y una etiqueta `table` fuera del `if`, pero luego **dentro del `if` cierras la etiqueta  `form` y también la etiqueta `table`** y luego también fuera del `if` cierras la etiqueta `form` y la etiqueta `table`. Antes que nada, comenta todo eso y haz únicamente un `var_dump($row);` dentro del `while` para verificar si está trayendo los datos.  Si los trae, entonces organiza mejor la tabla y el form que quieres construir con ellos, si no los trae entonces debes revisar la consulta y los datos que le pasas.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
$dato = mysqli_query($enlace, $sql); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dato)){

  var_dump($row);

}
```

y revisa que devuelve cada campo.

Comment: Por favor considera leer [ask] y si pudieras editar para explicar tu aporte sería genial